# Задать zoom в зависимости от размера circle. Mapkit для Android

Tags: android, kotlin, yandex-maps-api

Как максимально приблизить карту до такого размера, чтоб объект circle был полностью виден на экране? Радиус circle динамический поэтому подобрать его не совсем возможно. Mapkit для Android приложения

Comment: Решили этот вопрос?

Comment: Нет, тогда так и не удалось победить данный вопрос. Как сейчас обстоят дела с этим не знаю, может уже есть решение

Answer (score 1):

Вам не нужно угадывать масштаб самостоятельно. Используйте значения границ круга для того, чтобы задать видимую область карты:

```
myMap.setBounds(myCircle.geometry.getBounds());
```

Comment: Может я что то не так делаю, но методов связанных с bounds у меня нет. Код добавления круга у меня такой
mapView.map.addMapObjectLayer("test").addCircle(Circle(point, radius), Color.TRANSPARENT, 2F, Color.BLACK)

Comment: Прошу прощения, не заметил, что вопрос о MapKit. Следовало бы прописать это в вопросе, а не только в тегах. Тогда ответ не в тему.